# Schema design to avoid nested pagination

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

First of all, I am using a simplified version of "Relay" pagination where "List" is a basic equivalent of "connection" and "limit" is the equivalent to "first" and "cursor" is the equivalent to "after".

This is the relevant part of my schema:

```
extend type Query {
    artist(id: ID!): Artist
    artists(limit: Int!, cursor: String): ArtistList!
}

type Artist {
    id: ID!
    account: Account!
    photos(limit: Int!, cursor: String): PhotoList!
    website: String
    instagram: String
    facebook: String
    created: Date!
    updated: Date
    about: String
}

type ArtistList {
    nodes: [Artist]!
    page: Page!
}
```

I want avoid nested pagination, so want permit get next nodes of `photos` on the query `artist` and not permit get next nodes of `photos` on the query `artists` (For example, permit the argument `cursor` of `photos` on query `artist` and ban it on query `artists`). But I can't see how to express that in the GraphQL schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want to do specifically. You could return different types from `artist` (e.g. `ArtistWithPagination`) and from `artists` (e.g. `ArtistWithoutPagination`). I am not sure if this would be worth the tradeoff of having two very similar types.

Alternatively, you could throw a runtime error when a user attempts to query the API in this undesired way (with a [custom validation rule](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/validation/)). If your GraphQL API is internal you could even develop a linter, that warns developers if they do the double pagination in their queries.

Comment: I was assuming it wasn't possible, but I have little experience with GraphQL and wanted to make sure. I will read the docs about `validation`. Another possibility I was thinking about, is redesign the API, never to allow pagination through type `artist` and to get the same result, execute two queries on one request (I'm not sure if this is a correct approach from the point of view of GraphQL, or it can be problematic).

Comment: Yes, you could think about a separate query `photosByArtistId(id: ID!)` to fetch the photos. But I am not sure if you are really solving a problem here (or if this is some kind of premature optimisation/engineering bikeshedding). I can't really think of how a user would attempt to paginate twice.

Comment: You're right, it's a private API for a small app. I need to avoid premature and possibly unnecessary optimizations.